# v-for on the same level with v-if affects v-else

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

If I do this:

```
<ul>
<li v-for="value in testData">
  <span v-if="Array.isArray(value)" v-for="morevalue in value"> {‌{ morevalue }}</span>
  <span v-else> {‌{ value }} </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

The span in v-else will also be looped ON THE SECOND V-FOR even though it doesn't have any v-for on it, why?

This is the Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#exercise',
    data: {
        testData: {
        name: 'TESTOBJECT', 
        id: 10,
        data: [1.67, 1.33, 0.98, 2.21]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That is because of the outer `v-for` it is encapsulated in.

Comment: Well, you have **two** `v-for`s...

Answer (score 4):

`v-for` has a higher priority than `v-if`, (ie) `v-if` will be executed for each loop. If you want to skip execution of the `v-for` based on the `v-if`. I would recommend nesting the loop within the condition.

```
<ul>
<li v-for="value in testData">
  <template v-if="Array.isArray(value)"> 
    <span v-for="morevalue in value"> {‌{ morevalue }} ></span>
  </template>
  <span v-else> {‌{ value }} </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: However, your code is right, the justification is wrong. The v-if is the one with higher priority, this means will run first that the v-for.

Source: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-with-v-if

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like that:

```
<div v-if="!!arr?.length">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="value in arr">

      // ...

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```